# Problema con Página de documentación técnica HTML y CSS

Tags: html, css

Llevo dos semanas intentando resolver el porque me sale este mensaje:"#Layout

```
1. On regular sized devices (laptops, desktops), the element with id="navbar" should be shown on the left half of the screen. It should always be visible to the user and should remain stationary. You may need to enlarge the viewport or zoom out to ensure the navbar doesn't scroll with the page content."
```

No se que más hacer y quiero certificarme en diseño web, les dejo el link dónde está el código:
https://codepen.io/marco-gonzalez-blanco/pen/JjbzQmX

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: A que te refieres, ese mensaje donde sale, en la consola, al dar click en algun link? por favor se mas especifico con tu pregunta y crea un [example]

Comment: l dar en la ventana de "Run Test", aparece ese error, es para certificarme en freecodecamp

Comment: En la pregunta está el link a la página dónde esta mi código y el script de prueba.